# How to correctly imply the relationship between cyclic matrix and $\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^n-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, circulant-matrices

How to correctly say the following:

> Circulant matrix of size $n \times n$ is isomorphic to a ring
>   $\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^n-1)$

Isomorphic is a strong relationship and may not be suitable here. What I am trying to imply in above sentence is that we can represent a polynomial  with integer coefficients as a list of it's coefficients. Then multiply that polynomial by $x^i$ for $0\le i < n$, it would be equal to the rows of cyclic matrix.

Comment: @Arthur They're equal, though: if you take a circulant matrix with $c_1 = 1$ and $c_j=0$ for $j \ne 1$, that's just the permutation matrix for the $n$-cycle $(1\;2\;\cdots\;n)$.

Comment: If $P(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of some integer matrix $M$ then the matrix ring $\mathbb{Z}[M]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(P(x))$. So maybe you meant a particular circulant matrix with minimal polynomial $x^n-1$ ?

Comment: @Misha Of course. I misread circulant matrix and thought of a general matrix of finite multiplicative order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly say that the circulant matrices with integer coefficients form a ring which is isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^n-1)$.

In fact, we can even give an isomorphism: if $X$ is the first orthogonal circulant matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}
 0&0&\ldots&0&1\\
 1&0&\ldots&0&0\\
 0&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
 \vdots&\ddots&\ddots&0&0\\
 0&\ldots&0&1&0
\end{bmatrix}$$ then we can write uniquely any integer circulant matrix as $\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} a_m X^m$ with $a_m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Using that $X^{m+n} = X^m$ we get that the set of integer circulant matrix is naturally a ring isomorphic to $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^n-1)$.

Comment: If $C$ is the set of $n\times n$ circulant matrices, it is a ring by the properties of convolution. But I'm not sure how it is related to $x^n-1$ and $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^n-1)$, nor what you mean with "write any circulant matrix as a polynomial in $X$"

Comment: @user1952009 For example, if $n=3$, we can write a circulant matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c\\c & a & b\\b & c & a\end{bmatrix}$ as $aI + bX + cX^2$ where $X = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\\1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: As a note, your matrix $X$ is the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of the polynomial $x^n - 1$.  One can show that its minimal polynomial is $x^n - 1$, which would prove your claim about the kernel, I think.

Comment: @Quasicoherent I see it now, tks. @ Misha I edited your answer (but you can edit it)

Comment: @user1952009 Thank you!